# How to remove markers when use Leaflet Slider to show changes over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, leaflet

I am using Leaflet Slider, of Dennis Wilhelm, to try to show changes in data over a period of five years in a Leaflet map.

I am trying to get that when the user move the cursor over the slider, some marker disappear and some other appear. So far, I only get that the new marker appear on top of the old marker. 
So, my question is:

How can I remove markers when use Leaflet Slider to show changes over time? What changes I have to do in the original `SliderControl.js`?

Thanks in advance!

Below is the link to Dennis Wilhelm's Leaflet Slider code:

https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, but for anyone who is looking for it now. If you want to show changes over time and want to show specific points at a time, pass the parameter `follow` as `true`, so the slider would show only one point at a time.

```
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
   position: "topleft",
   layer: layername,
   follow: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to update markers in Leaflet I add my markers to a [layergroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup).  I then add that layer group to the map once, and clear it before adding new markers.  Below is a code snippet of what it might look like.  That way all markers are cleared out before adding new ones.  I hope that helps you.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
var markerLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();

map.addLayer(markerLayerGroup);

function addMarkers() {
   markerLayerGroup.clearLayers();
   markerLayerGroup.addLayer(markerVariable);
}
```

Comment: Is there or is there not a way to remove items from the layer? I don't want to remove the whole layer and redraw it each time I need to add data to it or remove data from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the **range: true** property to overcome this issue in a project i'm working on.

It is suboptimal however given that you need to move 2 sliders, both a Left and right slider, which represent the limits of the period you're interested in viewing, rather than just one for say a month end snapshot.

Also one increment of the slider will add 1 point to the map rather than adding a whole lot at once.

I expect there are solutions to these problems by extending the class but i've not had the time to do that yet.

here's my code:

```
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
   position: "topleft",
   layer: membMarksCurrent,
   range: true
});

map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();
```